# Unable to target a nested object in JSON by using dot notation

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, express

I am using mongoose and express to access data within MongoDB and I can see the JSON when I make a reference to the database, but when I try to target an object nested inside, I get an undefined message.

**JS file to access DB.**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const skate_tricks = require('../models/SkateTrick');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    skate_tricks.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Results snippet using Postman**

```
[
    {
        "trick_type": [],
        "_id": "5f34a5782e0d2fe1c2847633",
        "tricks": [
            {
                "trick_id": 0,
                "trick_name": "ollie",
                "trick_type": [
                    "flat"
                ],
                "trick_difficulty": "n",
                "trick_description": "Fundamental trick involving jumping with the skateboard. Performed by popping the tail with the back foot and sliding the front foot up towards the nose of the board. The sliding action levels the board while you are airborn."
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to access the "tricks" array of objects directly, but it's not working.

```
res.send(result.tricks);
```

Comment: It seems `result` is an array, you need to use `result[0].tricks` to get the value.

Comment: Your result var is an array hence you need to access it `result[0].tricks` like this

Comment: @HaoWu When I try to console log it out with your method, I'm still getting undefined. I noticed that too, but not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Maybe you can try `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)))` to see what's actually in it

Comment: @HaoWu I'm getting the same result in the console. It shows that the data is wrapped in an array with square brackets. I've worked with JSON before, but never ran into this issue.

Comment: did you try `console.log(typeof result)`

Comment: @Ifaruki When I do "typeof result[0]" in console.log it shows that it's an object. When I try to do "result[0].tricks" it shows undefined still.

Comment: what does `result[0]` shows?

Comment: @Ifaruki result[0] shows 
`{
  trick_type: [],
  _id: 5f44a2e5f0776ca5c29fff93,
  tricks: [
    {
      trick_id: 0,
      trick_name: 'ollie',
      trick_type: [Array],
      trick_difficulty: 'n',
      trick_description: 'Fundamental trick involving jumping with the skateboard. Performed by popping the tail with the back foot and sliding the front foot up towards the nose of the board. The sliding action levels the board while you are airborn.'
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: hmm okey. could you show us your mongoose model?

Comment: @Ifaruki sure here it is: `const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const SkateTrickSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 trick_id: {
  type: Number,
  required: true,
  unique: true,
 },
 trick_name: {
  type: String,
  unique: true,
 },
 trick_type: {
  type: Array,
  required: true,
 },
 trick_difficulty: {
  type: String,
  required: false,
 },
 trick_description: {
  type: String,
  required: false,
 },
});

module.exports = SkateTrick = mongoose.model(
 'skateboard-tricks',
 SkateTrickSchema
);`

Comment: you have no `tricks` in your mongoose model schema

Comment: @Ifaruki The schema is for the trick objects in the tricks array of objects. Do I need to have 2 separate schemas? One for the tricks array and one of the tricks themselves?

Comment: @Sako do you have an model where you save your data with `tricks` in it?

Comment: @Ifaruki No, that's the only model I have.

Comment: i have wrote an answer what you could try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `tricks` to your mongoose model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const SkateTrickSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  trick_id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
  trick_name: { type: String, unique: true },
  trick_type: { type: Array, required: true },
  trick_difficulty: { type: String, required: false },
  trick_description: { type: String, required: false },
  tricks: { type: Array, required: true }
});
module.exports = SkateTrick = mongoose.model(
  "skateboard-tricks",
  SkateTrickSchema
);
```

One thing what you can try is to add `.lean()` to your query

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let result = await skate_tricks.find({}).lean();
    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You result object is an array of object.

```
[
    {
        "trick_type": [],
        "_id": "5f34a5782e0d2fe1c2847633",
        "tricks": [
            {
                "trick_id": 0,
                "trick_name": "ollie",
                "trick_type": [
                    "flat"
                ],
                "trick_difficulty": "n",
                "trick_description": "Fundamental trick involving jumping with the skateboard. Performed by popping the tail with the back foot and sliding the front foot up towards the nose of the board. The sliding action levels the board while you are airborn."
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So you have to access it by using `res.send(result[0].tricks);` or change your API response to return it like

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that doesn't work for me. I am getting an undefined value when I do that.